# Remove adjacent_posts_rel_link under 3.2?

Tags: functions, wp-head

I'm trying to remove the adjacent_posts_rel_link links under WP3.2, i.e. remove these from wp_head:

```
<link rel='prev' title='blah blah' href='http://...' />
<link rel='next' title='blah blah' href='http://...' />
```

and this function used to work under 3.1:

```
function remove_header_info() {
remove_action('wp_head', 'adjacent_posts_rel_link', 10, 0);
}

add_action('init', 'remove_header_info');
```

But doesn't under 3.2. Anyone know or know how to find the new action to remove the links?

**Edit 7/15/11:** the change is `adjacent_posts_rel_link_wp_head`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer: the change in 3.2 is from `adjacent_posts_rel_link` to `adjacent_posts_rel_link_wp_head`